# Request and response format for IBM cloud storage object S3 API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I need information related request and response format for IBM cloud storage object S3 API.I have been searching through API doc and come across that it is only supporting XML response format.Question is, does it support Json format response? if yes,it would be really grateful provide details about objects and supporting APIs for which I can get Json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current [Amazon S3 API is dated 2006-03-01](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html). It encapsulates the metadata in XML documents, not in JSON. The [IBM Cloud Object Storage service offers a common subset of the S3 API](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/api-reference#overview). To be compatible, that API needs to follow the Amazon S3 API which is XML-based.

The answer to your question is that there is no JSON support, only XML.

Answer (score 0):

Henrik is correct in that the S3 API is XML-based, but depending on the SDK or tool used it's possible to get JSON, text, or table responses.

For example, [using the AWS CLI](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/cli) you can set the response type using `aws configure`, and then the output will be formatted appropriately.

JSON:

```
$ aws s3api --endpoint-url=https://{endpoint} s3api list-buckets
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "{access-key}",
        "ID": "{access-key}"
    },
    "Buckets": [
        {
            "CreationDate": "2016-11-09T16:43:29.957Z",
            "Name": "bucket-1"
        },
        {
            "CreationDate": "2017-06-13T23:47:18.169Z",
            "Name": "bucket-2"
        },
        {
            "CreationDate": "2017-05-01T02:36:34.385Z",
            "Name": "bucket-3"
        },
    ]
}
```

Text:

```
$ aws s3api --endpoint-url=https://{endpoint} s3api list-buckets
BUCKETS 2016-11-09T16:43:29.957Z    bucket-1
BUCKETS 2017-06-13T23:47:18.169Z    bucket-2
BUCKETS 2017-05-01T02:36:34.385Z    bucket-3
OWNER   {access-key}    {access-key}
```

Table:

```
$ aws s3api --endpoint-url=https://{endpoint} s3api list-buckets
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                ListBuckets                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
||                                 Buckets                                ||
|+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+|
||           CreationDate           |                Name                 ||
|+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+|
||  2016-11-09T16:43:29.957Z        |  bucket-1                           ||
||  2017-06-13T23:47:18.169Z        |  bucket-2                           ||
||  2017-05-01T02:36:34.385Z        |  bucket-3                           ||
|+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+|
||                                  Owner                                 ||
|+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+|
||            DisplayName            |                ID                  ||
|+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+|
||            {access-key}           |           {access-key}             ||
|+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+|
```